# How to forward query parameters to external identity provider using Keycloak?

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, identity

While creating an identity provider (IdP) in the Keycloak there is an option available to forward the query params to the external IdP. How can I use that?
[image]

I want to forward, say, `launch` parameter to the external IdP. I mentioned the `launch` in the `Forwarded Query Parameters` field in Keycloak configuration page. I'm using an app on my `locahost:9090` protected by Keyclaok. When I access `http://localhost:9090?launch=abc` this param is not forwarding to the external IdP. I'm using `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` for our Spring Boot app.

Also from the [code of Keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/broker/oidc/AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java#L344), I have seen that there is some prefix is attached to the forwarded parameter i.e. `client_request_param_` so I tried using `http://localhost:9090?client_request_param_launch=abc` but no luck.

`AuthorizationEndpoint.LOGIN_SESSION_NOTE_ADDITIONAL_REQ_PARAMS_PREFIX = client_request_param_`

```
String forwardParameterConfig = getConfig().getForwardParameters() != null ? getConfig().getForwardParameters(): "";
List<String> forwardParameters = Arrays.asList(forwardParameterConfig.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
for(String forwardParameter: forwardParameters) {
    String name = AuthorizationEndpoint.LOGIN_SESSION_NOTE_ADDITIONAL_REQ_PARAMS_PREFIX + forwardParameter.trim();
    String parameter = request.getAuthenticationSession().getClientNote(name);
    if(parameter != null && !parameter.isEmpty()) {
        uriBuilder.queryParam(forwardParameter, parameter);
    }
}
```

P.S: I'm using Keycloak 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with setting [acr_values parameters](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) in the authorization request. I resolved it by putting the parameter directly in the authorization endpoint path:

```
https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/authorize?acr_values=MY_VALUES&
```

I didn't investigate much, why *Forwarded Query Parameter* didn't work as expected (I'm using Keycloak 14.0.0). Happy to see if someone gives some explanation later here.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone encounter this. As implemented in the [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/5f2837def08daee8462cdb962391c34bc2167300/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/request/AuthzEndpointRequestParser.java#L113), there is a maximum limit of 5 additional query params (declared as constants: ADDITIONAL_REQ_PARAMS_MAX_MUMBER) for the processing of additional query params.

The additional query params are excluded from the subset of declared known req params (KNOWN_REQ_PARAMS declared [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/5f2837def08daee8462cdb962391c34bc2167300/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/request/AuthzEndpointRequestParser.java#L50)).

Example,

```
https://<domain>/openid-connect/auth?

scope=xx

&response_type=code

&client_id=xxx

&redirect_uri=xxx

&state=xxx

&addParam1=xx

&addParam2=xx

&addParam3=xx

&addParam4=xx

&addParam5=xx

&addParam6=xx (not processed)

&addParam7=xx (not processed)
```

Referring to the [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/5f2837def08daee8462cdb962391c34bc2167300/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/endpoints/request/AuthzEndpointRequestParser.java#L114), the extractAdditionalReqParams method will only process up to addParam5 and stop afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

I am guessing that the forwarded query parameters are the NON-OIDC parameters attached to the initial code flow request - those are then forwarded to the IdP, if specified in the list for that IdP.